# Linearly independent linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let  $ f_1,\ldots,f_n$ be linearly independent linear functionals on a vector space $X$. Show that there are $n$ elements  $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ in $X$ such that the $n\times n$ matrix $[f_i(x_j) ]$ is non-singular.